# Java - convert buffer to string (economical way)

Tags: java, string

I read something to buffer:

```
 char buf[] = new char[4096];     
 int got = reader.read(buf,0,4096);
```

readLine() is not OK because of the stuff can contain "\n" characters.

Then I nee to convert buf[] to String. String.valueOf(buf) will be of size buf.length() == 4096 and will contain junk at end. I need String of size *got*. There are 2 perverted way to do this. First way - create new array of size *got*, copy bytes to new array and do String.valueOf. Second way - append to String char by char converting each char to String.Is there better way not involving weird actions?

Comment: Why would you define it as "weird" actions"? You just listed two types of programmatic ways to convert a buffer of characters to a String. How, in your opinion, is this "perverted" or "weird"?

Comment: @Braj has the best answer below. Be sure to reference the javadocs to make sure there isn't something obvious you can do.

Answer (score 4):

> I need String of size `got`

You can use String constructor [String(char[] value,int offset,int count)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char[],%20int,%20int%29)

```
String s = new String(buf,0,got);
```

---

Sample code:

```
char buf[] = new char[4096];
buf[0]='a';
buf[1]='b';
buf[2]='c';
int got = 2;
String s = new String(buf,0,got);
System.out.println(s);      // ab
```

Comment: Thanks, this is that I searched for, did not know about this constructor existence.Weird ==  involves unnecessary memory and CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringBuffer. This is like a String, but mutable. So, for example, something like:

```
StringBuffer sbuff = new StringBuffer();
sbuff.append(buf);
sbuff.setLength(got);
String buffString = sbuff.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a StringBuilder with [`append(char[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char[],%20int,%20int%29) like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char buf[] = new char[4096];
int got = reader.read(buf,0,4096);
sb.append(buf,0, got);
```